# Import data to Google Sheets from JavaScript with automatic column widths (v3 API)

Tags: javascript, csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm writing JavaScript browser/client-side code that needs to upload table/grid based data to Google Sheets and I'm having trouble setting column widths sensibly. The data is stored in JavaScript as arrays of arrays.

So far I've tried uploading the data formatted as a CSV file to "/upload/drive/v3/files" with a "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" MIME type set as part of the metadata. This works as in I can open the file in Drive as a Google Sheet. However, all the columns are the same size and tiny. Many of my cells contain around 300 characters of text so all the text is truncated and looks bad.

Ideally the columns would resize to fit the longest entry. If I could set the width by value that would work as well.

I need to upload around 100 tables so they need to be either separate files or separate sheets on a single spreadsheet. I want to reduce the number of API calls I need to make as I have many users.

Ideas I've thought of:

- Upload as above then use up extra API calls to change the dimensions of the columns. Not what I want to do given there's about 100 tables.
- Is there a way to use the Drive API to create the file then the Sheets API to add the data with column widths specified? I'd rather do everything with one request per table if possible though.
- Convert the data in JS to Excel or OpenOfffice format data with the column width encoded and upload that. Would this work? This feels complex though if there's alternatives.

I'm surprised if there's not a way to make Google Sheets resize the columns automatically on upload as it seems a common expectation when importing CSV data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a spreadsheet with 100 sheets from CSV files. When a table from CSV data is imported to a sheet, you want to create new sheet and import the table. And then, you want to automatically modify the length of columns. If my understanding is correct, how about this method?

I thought that `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate` can achieve your situation. `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate` can sequentially run the batch process by adding methods to the request array.  A simple sample for your situation is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Create a new sheet in Spreadsheet of `### fileId ###`.

   - You can give freely `sheetId` as Int32. This sample uses `1000000001`.
2. Import data to the created sheet.

   - Please import each row of the CSV data to `pasteData`. This sample gives 2 rows.
   - `delimiter` is `,`.
3. Resize the column width using `autoResizeDimensions`.

   - By this, the column width is resized automatically by the length of imported values.

In this sample, these flow can be run by one API call.

#### Endpoint

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### fileId ###:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body :

```
{
  "requests":[
    {"addSheet":{"properties":{"title":"sssample","sheetId":1000000001}}},
    {"pasteData":{"data":"##########sampletext1##########,##########sampletext2##########,##########sampletext3##########","delimiter":",","coordinate":{"rowIndex":0,"columnIndex":0,"sheetId":1000000001}}},
    {"pasteData":{"data":"##########sampletext4##########,##########sampletext5##########,##########sampletext6##########","delimiter":",","coordinate":{"rowIndex":0,"columnIndex":0,"sheetId":1000000001}}},
    {"autoResizeDimensions":{"dimensions":{"dimension":"COLUMNS","sheetId":1000000001,"startIndex":0,"endIndex":3}}}
  ]
}
```

#### Note :

- Please modify above sample request body for your situation.
- If you have already created the sheets, please remove `addSheet` from the request body.
- I couldn't know the limitation for the number of methods in the request body, so if you have the limitation in your situation, please separate it.

#### References :

- [sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [addSheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#add_a_sheet)
- [pasteData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#PasteDataRequest)
- [autoResizeDimensions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AutoResizeDimensionsRequest)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting the cells, check the [Basic Formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting) guide. It includes instructions on how to specify the size of the width. Other supported methods are found in the [Sheets API reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) which includes [creating spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create).

Comment: For 100 sheets though, isn't this going to require 100 API calls to upload the data and then 100 calls to change the column widths? If I want finer control over each column width it's going to be even worse so this isn't sounding like a good solution. There's no way to specify the column width on upload?

Comment: same concept, but this time, try [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate).

Comment: Thanks but batch update still uses up the same number of API calls so it isn't much better. Can you confirm there's no way for sure to do this in less API calls?